# Addressing directory in python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I make this program and it has an error. I thinks it's related to the addressing.

```
import os 
def renamefi():
    filist=os.listdir(r"D:\Data\Personal-Education\Personal Work\Python Learning Project\Soppurted Files\prank")
    savepath=os.getcwd()
    os.chdir=(r"D:\Data\Personal-Education\Personal Work\Python Learning Project\Soppurted Files\prank")
    for finame in filist :
        os.renames(finame, finame.strip("012345678"))
renamefi()
```

and this is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\Data\Personal-Education\Personal Work\Python Learning
>   Project\Udacity-2_Rename.py", line 9, in 
>       renamefi()   File "D:\Data\Personal-Education\Personal Work\Python Learning Project\Udacity-2_Rename.py", line 8, in renamefi
>       os.renames(finame, finame.strip("012345678"))   File "C:\Python34\lib\os.py", line 282, in renames
>       rename(old, new) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '.DS_Store' -> '.DS_Store' [Finished in 0.1s]

editor screen shot:
http://s3.picofile.com/file/8201944476/address.jpg

Comment: `os.renames(finame, finame.strip("012345678")` should be `os.renames(finame, finame.strip("012345678"))`.

Comment: You'll need to put spaces/a tab before `os.renames` because Python uses whitespace to determine what is and isn't inside a block of code for loops, if blocks and function definitions.

Comment: Why is this tagged "syntax-error"?

Comment: @skyking It used to be a syntax error, but they were fixed. :-)

Comment: The facts that the \D and \S in that editor screenshot are red and italic is worrying.

Comment: yes
and how can I fix it?

Comment: @LennartRegebro: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code

Comment: @SiHa: I updated it to match what he actually had. See screenshot and comments.

Comment: @SeyedAmirMousavian That depends entirely on why it is like that, which I don't know. I've never seen anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent:

```
for finame in filist :
os.renames(finame, finame.strip("012345678")
```

Should be

```
for finame in filist:
    os.renames(finame, finame.strip("012345678")
```

And it's also missing the end parenthesis:

```
for finame in filist :
    os.renames(finame, finame.strip("012345678"))
```

Also you forgot a backslash in one of the filenames. It should be "D:\Data".

Comment: There's also a missing )

Comment: If you correct both those things, there are no more syntax error. I tested.

Comment: You forgot a backslash. It's "D:\Data"

Comment: This is why, when developing, you write only a few lines of code at a time, before testing. That way you don't have three errors at once, so often.

Comment: I think I fix all of that.

Comment: Then the file you specified does not exist. Perhaps the directory is not called "Soppurted"?